# React - Conditionally Show Block Based on Query String Parameter Value

Tags: reactjs

I have an app using React. It includes the React Router. In one of my components, I need to read the query string, and conditionally show one block if the query string parameter has a value. If the value is not present in the query string, I want to show another block.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container} from 'reactstrap';
import {NavMenu} from './NavMenu';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render() {
    return {
      <div>
        <NavMenu />  <!-- I want to hide this is query string has hideNav=true -->
        <Container>  <!-- I want to use a fluid layout if the query string has hideNav=true -->
          {this.prop.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

How do I conditionally render content based on the query string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have params in your react router routes you can get those via `this.props.match.params`:

```
export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render() {
    const {hideNav} = this.props.match.params;
    return {
      <div>
        {!hideNav && <NavMenu />} // Render NavMenu if hideNav is false
        <Container fluid={hideNav}>  
          {this.prop.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to represent a quick example let me suggest a URL with a query string parameter what the code operates with. It's called `hideNav` as below:

> https://yourawesomewebsite.com/?hideNav=true

**As a first step:**

We need to get the query string what you need work with in your `render` method. There are quite a couple of options to get the query parameters, let me summarize here:

**1. Using the window object**

```
let queryString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let hideNav = queryString.get('hideNav');
```

Read further about `URLSearchParams` in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). Highlighted from the mentioned URL:

> The `URLSearchParams` interface defines utility methods to work with the query string of a URL.

**2. Using the React Router way**

```
let queryString = this.props.match.params;
let hideNav = queryString.hideNav;
```

Please follow [this link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md) if you want to read further. Additionally let me highlight below the key point here:

> `params` - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path

**As a second step:**

The code needs to use the conditional rendering based on the value.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Container} from 'reactstrap';
import {NavMenu} from './NavMenu';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render() {
    const hideNav = // here you can decide based on the above explanation which one you want to use

    return {
      <div>
        { !hideNav ? <NavMenu /> : null }
        <Container fluid={hideNav}>
          {this.prop.children}
        </Container>
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

About `fluid` container you can read further [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/#grid-props):

> fluid (boolean) - Allow the Container to fill all of it's available horizontal space.

So basically rendering `NavMenu` once the `hideNav` value is `true` other than that React renders `null`. On the `Container` the code is using the `fluid` property to manipulate the horizontal space.

Comment: I don't understand `fluid`. Just because it doesn't take up the space doesn't mean it's not rendered, am I correct?

Comment: I guess what is wanted here is hiding the `NavMenu` once we have in the URL the `hideNav` value as `true`. Thus the `Container` can fill all the other space in. I assume that's why the fluid is needed here. I have also changed from `!hideNav` to `hideNav` in `Container`. My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Hi check these conditions based example

```
class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hideNave: false
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://url')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.date) {
          this.setState({
            hideNave: true
          })
        }
      });
  }
  render() {
    return
    (<div>
      { this.state.hideNave ?  (<NavMenu />) :  (<Container> {this.prop.children} </Container>) }
    </div>)
  }
}
```